# Extracting the info from Outlook to Excel

Tags: vba, outlook

I have the code below which gives me the Sender line, Subject line and date information, however is there a way to also get the information from the To line (Name and Email Address).

```vb
Sub GetFromOutlook()
    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
    Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
    Dim OutlookMail As Variant
    Dim I As Integer

    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Mail").Folders("Test")

    I = 1

    For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
        If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("From_date").Value Then
         Range("eMail_subject").Offset(I, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Subject
         Range("eMail_date").Offset(I, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
         Range("eMail_sender").Offset(I, 0).Value = OutlookMail.SenderName
         Range("eMail_text").Offset(I, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Body
            I = I + 1
        End If
    Next OutlookMail

    Set Folder = Nothing
    Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Start with [`MailItem.To`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.to) perhaps. Or maybe better, [`MailItem.Recipients`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.recipients).

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all recipients in the MailItem.Recipients collection. If you only need To recipients, check the Recipient.Type property - it ca be olTo, olCC, olBCC

```
for each recip in OutlookMail .Recipients
  if recip.Type = olTo Then
     MsgBox recip.Name & ": " & recip.Address
  End If
next
```

As a sidenote, the condition  `If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("From_date").Value` will never be satisfied - you cannot use equality comparison for the datetime values, you only only use a range: `(value < const1) and (value > const2)`